# Error with top view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, rootviewcontroller

I have one difficulty with the root view controller.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRaeI.png) Picture(1)

Within the below code and the picture 1, everything work fine. 
But within picture 2 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skMjT.png) Picture (2), I got an error said that

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BannerViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feb9b64dbc0'`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];

    ItemListTableViewController *itemList = (ItemListTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
    itemList.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

So please help me how to insert a view controller in front of the navigation controller?

Comment: Your `UINavigationController` is actually `BannerViewController`. You have to check this line `UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the navigation controller through the `childViewControllers` property of the container VC:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *containerVC = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
    UIView *containerVCview = containerVC.view;
    UINavigationController *navController = containerVC.childViewControllers[0];

    ItemListTableViewController *itemList = (ItemListTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
    itemList.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: After applying your code, I got another error saying: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'" What should I do?

Comment: @borinprak Hmm... seems like the container VC has not yet instantiated the child view controller.  Let me test some ideas.....

Comment: @borinprak To force the containerVC to load its view, and therefore the childVC, just access its view - I'll amend code accordingly.